# Number of ways of merging two ordered lists

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I want to find number of ways of ordering two ordered list with different number of elements.

For example, I have two ordered list L1 = [A, B, C] and L2 = [1, 2]
In how many ways can I arrange elements of both the list such that when elements of only one list are considered, they are ordered? Such merged lists are : [A,1,B,2,C], [A,B,C,1,2], [A,1,2,B,C], [1,2,A,B,C], [1,A,B,C,2].... (there are <del>20</del> 10 (as corrected by @Ross Millikan) such lists if I am not wrong)

How do I find the number of such possible lists? Insight on how the answer was deduced would help in future too

Comment: I had asked (and later, answered) a similar question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4643737/all-possible-permutations-of-joining-merging-two-lists-circular-vs-non-circul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have as many slots in the total list as in the sum of the two starting lists.  Then you just need to choose which slots receive elements of the first list. Everything else is determined by that.  If both lists must be ordered as subsets of the merged list, I believe there are $10$ merged lists in your example, not $20$

Comment: +1: So much more straightforward than the approach I was in the midst of describing....

Comment: You are right. I get that. I will edit the question. However, when the individual lists are long, this may become cumbersome. Is there a formula to calculate?

Comment: Yes, you are just asking the number of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of (total number of items=$n$) choose (number of items in list 1=$r$), which is ${n \choose r}=\frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$